# Stop reopening same window

Tags: java, netbeans, jinternalframe

I just code simple logic to stop opening same window when I click the same button..

[image]
when I click Item return,that internal frame should `setvisible` in below `jdesktoppane` highlighted in black frame..If that already opened just see that no reopening.. same to warranty..But this not work just tell me a way to do that..

```
Item_Return ir;
try {
        if (ir == null) {
            ir = new Item_Return();
        }
        jDesktopPane3.add(ir).setVisible(true);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
```

if I double click that button I got this exception too`illegal component position`

Comment: FYI on spelling: the word "warranty" has an "a" not an "e".

Comment: hey guys....help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html). It contains a working example that shows you how to dynamically create and display in internal frame.